# c# Accessing attributes of an entity after having made sure it implements an interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, poco

I need to have certain attributes of my POCO entities updated on certain actions.

I defined the following Interfaces:

```
public interface IEntityPOCO
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IHasLastChange : IEntityPOCO
{
    DateTime LastChange { get; set; }
}
```

Here's an example action method:

```
public void SomeStuff<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntityPOCO
{
    entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); // Works like a charm.

    if (entity is IHasLastChange)
    {
        entity.LastChange = DateTime.Now; // Doesn't work. D'oh.
        (IHasLastChange)entity.LastChange = DateTime.Now; // Doesn't work either.
    }
}
```

- Since there's quite a lot of different properties (all with corresponding Interfaces) that might be implemented by the POCO, going about the problem with different function signatures is pretty much out of question.
- I'd rather not use reflection for performance reasons.

Is there any feasible way to put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need more `()` in the casting:

```
 // (IHasLastChange)entity.LastChange = DateTime.Now;
   ((IHasLastChange)entity).LastChange = DateTime.Now;
```

> Since there's quite a lot of different properties

Then it will quickly pay to use a temp var:

```
if (entity is IHasLastChange)
{
    lastChange = (IHasLastChange) entity;
    lastChange.LastChange = DateTime.Now; 
    lastChange. ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The common way to do this would be to cast the entity with `as` and check if it's `null`, like this:

```
var lastChangedEntity = entity as IHasLastChange;
if (lastChangedEntity != null)
{
    lastChangedEntity.LastChange = DateTime.Now;
}
```

But this leads to a nasty code smell as the number of different interfaces increase.

If this is the case, consider using the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52807/Design-Patterns-Part-1-The-Strategy-Pattern) to handle it, in that way you will adhere to the [Open/Closed Principle (OCP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and make your application more maintainable.

**EDIT:** A Strategy Pattern example would be:

```
public void SomeStuff<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntityPOCO
{
    entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); // Works like a charm.

    // _processors is a List<IProcessEntities>
    var processors = _processors.Where(p => p.CanProcess(entity));

    foreach (var processor in processors)
    {
        processor.Process(entity);
    }
}

public interface IProcessEntities
{
    bool CanProcess<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntityPOCO;

    void Process<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntityPOCO;
}

public class LastChangedProcessor : IProcessEntities
{
    public bool CanProcess<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntityPOCO
    {
        return typeof(IHasLastChange).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
    }

    public void Process<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntityPOCO
    {
        var lastChangeEntity = entity as IHasLastChange;
        if (lastChangeEntity != null) 
        {
            lastChangeEntity.LastChange = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast.

```
var hasLastChange = entity as IHasLastChange;
hasLastChange.LastChange = DateTime.Now; //It works!
```

Or

```
((IHasLastChange)entity).LastChange = DateTime.Now; //It also works!
```